# ExpressJS res.render not working with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angularjs-routing

I am pretty new to Node.js, Express and angularjs. I am working on a simple Sign-in functionality that will redirect to another page if sign in success. I know I can use window.location for the redirect purpose, but I am trying to use res.render because I also want to pass some values to the new page.

However, the res.render doesn't seem to work, the result page never shows up.

Signin.ejs:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" ng-controller="signinController">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" ng-model="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" ng-model="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="signIn()" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
      </form>
</div>
```

The javascript embedded is:

```
function signinController($scope,$http,$location) {

    $scope.signIn = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/signin',
            data: { "inputEmail": $scope.inputEmail, "inputPassword": $scope.inputPassword }

         });
    };
}
```

app.js

```
app.get('/result', home.result);
app.post('/signin', home.afterSignIn);
```

The home.js

```
    function afterSignIn(req,res)
{
    // check user already exists
    var sqlStr="select * from users where email='"+req.param("inputEmail")+"' and password='"+req.param("inputPassword")+"'";
console.log("Query is:"+sqlStr);
res.render('result', { result: 'sqlStr' });
}

exports.result=function(req,res){
    res.render('result');
}
exports.afterSignIn = afterSignIn;
```

result.ejs

```
<%= result %>
```

Any suggestions or working examples are highly appreciated :)

Comment: you'll need to use res.redirect. Consider setting the values to the session, then retrieving them in the new route, and passing them to your view there

Answer (score 1):

I think you are bit confused. Use express as the **REST** engine when it comes to routes. **Angular routes** will take care of the display logic and view routing on the client side.

I would suggest you to pass JSON data to front end angular and let it do the job for you. For example:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json({
    title : "n562d", 
    strapline : "Please Log In"
  })
});
```

You can access the API at the endpoint: http://localhost:3000/ Use [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) services to access the express endpoint.

example:

```
var MyResource = $resource('/');
 var myResource = new MyResource();
 myResource.$get(function(result){
   //result holds -->{title : "n562d", strapline : "Please Log In"}
   //use $location to change the uri, which is handled by Angular route config
   $location.path('/') 
 });
```

For angular routing,i would suggest you to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

example:

```
function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

     $stateProvider
     .state('index', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: 'app/authorization/index.tpl.html',
      controller: 'AuthController'
    })
     .state('login', {
      url: "/login/",
      templateUrl: 'app/authorization/login.tpl.html',
      controller: 'AuthController'
    })
    .state('signup',{
      url: "/signup/",
      templateUrl : 'app/authorization/signup.tpl.html',
      controller: 'AuthController'
    });
}
]);
```

Let me know if you need more detailed answer then i will update it. I hope it helps.

Feel free to look for similar implementation [here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-todo-app).

Comment: But how do you initially serve the Angular app to the user?

Comment: Sorry i didn't understood, what do mean by "initially serve"? Do you mean accessing the home page ?